# Efficient way to merge two similar objects (where only few fields are different)

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having a challenge (or) confusion on good/efficient way to solve this challenge.

I have List. Here CustomObject has around 20 filed/attribute. In this list I might have sort of duplicate items (means except 4 fields every field would be same). Need to merge these two records into one record and merge 4 fields (which is business logic I can deal).

Now identifying these **"sort of duplicate items"** is what I am struggling with. Here are few approaches I am thinking of:

Use HashMap and use "Concatenated string of all similar attributes" as key and store the "sort of duplicates as value List for the given key. The problem I feel is, KEY for the map will be HUGE (like around 3000+ characters and could be clumsy)

Override equals method and make a Set to store the CustomObject. If exists, override the 4 fields based on business logic and save this new object. Lookup cost for if exists.

N X N approach. Looping through NX N which I feel doesn't make sense and expensive as number of items in the list increases.

Appreciate any other thoughts on best way to resolve this. Thank you!

Comment: This Question could use a contrived example, after simplifying to a few fields rather than 20.

Comment: When you say, "duplicate", are you referring to field names in common or field values in common?

Comment: @phatfingers field values in common.

Comment: A bitmap of which fields have the same value for a given pair of records would be functionally equivalent to a "Concatenated string of all similar attributes" and would only take up an int.  I fear I'm not quite understanding a deterministic goal, though.  For example, `[{a:1,b:1,c:1}, {a:1,b:1,c:2}, {a:2,b:1,c:2}]` have two different ways that records could be merged with 2 fields in common and one not in common.  Can you articulate some sort of test or example to know if you merged correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an efficient way to identify how similar one field collection is to another field collection, you could associate each collection of fields with a bitmap.  You mention around 20 potential fields, which would fit comfortably within an int.

This method would generate a lookup of values to associate with each field.

```
private Map<String,Integer> bitmapFields(String[] fieldList) {
    Map<String,Integer> bitValue=new HashMap<>();
    for (int i=0; i<fieldList.length; i++) {
        bitValue.put(fieldList[i],(2<<i));
    }
    return bitValue;
}
private int bitmap(String[] customFields, Map<String,Integer> mappedValues) {
    int fieldBitmap=0;
    for (String customField : customFields) {
        fieldBitmap+=mappedValues(customField);
    }
    return fieldBitmap;
}
```

Assuming your CustomObject maintained a value, int fieldBitmap, whenever it's collection of fields is defined.  Then, the effort of comparing field commonalities between two CustomObjects is reduced.

```
public static int fieldsInCommon(int bitmapA, int bitmapB) {
    return Integer.bitCount(bitmapA & bitmapB);
}
public static int fieldsNotInCommon(int bitmapA, int bitmapB) {
    return Integer.bitCount(bitmapA ^ bitmapB);
}
```

You'd still face an NxN comparison, but both the memory and compute costs would be trivial, even for a large dataset.